# Можно ли задать Spannable Formatted String в ресурсах?

Tags: android, текст, style, resources

Задача такая

есть время, количество минут, из него надо показать что-то вроде

**n** h **m** min

или

**m** min

если часов нет

Звучит довольно просто

подход номер один

создаём ресурсы

```
<string name="t_long">%1d %2s %3d %4s</string>

<string name="t_short">%1d %2s</string>
```

пишем код

```
private static CharSequence time(Context context, int minutes) {
    int h = minutes % 60;
    int m = minutes / 60;

    final String min = String.valueOf(m);
    final String hour = String.valueOf(h);


    String mUnits = getMinuteUnits(context); // Берём из текущей локализации
    String hUnits = getHourUnits(context); // Берем из текущей локаизации
    String time;
    if (hours == 0) {
        time = context.getString(R.string.t_short, m, mUnits);
    } else {
        time = context.getString(R.string.t_long, h, hUnits, m, mUits);
    }

    final Spannable s = new SpannableString(time);

    if (h == 0) {
        int minStartIndex = time.indexOf(min);

        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif-medium"), minStartIndex, min.length(), Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif"), min.length() + 1, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
    } else {
        int hStart = time.indexOf(min + " " + hUnits);
        int mStart = time.indexOf(hour + " " + mUnits);

        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif-medium"), hStart, hour.length(), Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif"), hour.length() + 1, mStart - 1, Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif-medium"), mStart, mStart + min.length(), Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif"), mStart + min.length() + 1, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_POINT_POINT);

    }

    return s;
}
```

Казалось бы это всё, однако. Однако внезапно появился юзер, который сломал эту логику, потому что не во всех локалях цифры арабские. Перед спаном конкатенация, а строку надо искать форматированную. Не большая проблема, поправить недолго, однако мне вспомнилось, что есть такая вот замечательная статья

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/styling-internationalized-text-in-android-f99759fb7b8f

там строки стилизуются прямо в ресурсах. Однако у всех этих подходов есть *фатальный недостаток*, они работают только со статичными строками. Если строковый ресурс будет выглядеть как

```
<string name="t_short"><b>5</b> min</string>
```

то

```
textView.setText(R.string.t_short)
```

сработает, но

```
context.getString(int, args...) 

context.getResourses().getText(int)

context.getResourses().getQuantityString(int,int,int)
```

возвращают строку, а не спанаабл

Пробовал и аннотации, тожепрекрасно все извлекается, только `SpannableString` не позволяет  делать replaceSpan

Собственно так и зародился вопрос, а есть способ засунуть в ресурсы отспаненную строку с форматными аргументами?

Comment: _`SpannableString` не позволяет делать `replaceSpan`_ - `SpannableStringBuilder ssb =  new SpannableStringBuilder(anySpannedOrNotText);` и в этом билдере можно делать что угодно. `context.getResourses().getText(int)` - этот метод возвращает `CharSequence` со спанами (если они есть).

Comment: @woess То, что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Совместить тэги с форматированием!? - приходит на ум такое решение:

```
<!-- содержимое ![CDATA[...]] будет отдаваться как есть вместе с тэгами -->
<string name="t_short"><![CDATA[<b>%d</b> min]]></string>
```

---

```
// форматируем
String formatted = context.getString(R.string.t_short, 5);
Spanned spanned;
// конвертируем тэги в спаны
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    spanned = Html.fromHtml(formatted, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
} else {
    spanned = Html.fromHtml(formatted);
}
// выводим
textView.setText(spanned);
```